# grep and search and replace in linux accepting parameters with /

Tags: linux, grep, bash-scripting, find-and-replace

I'm trying to find and replace the contents of a file using grep and sed.

`grep "#!/bin/bash" ./ | sed xargs -i 's/#!/bin/bash/#!/usr/bin/env bash'`

How do I make sure that the string `#!/bin/bash` will parse as string and not confused the demiliter `/`?

Comment: Use ´\´ to escape '/' in your search/replacement strings.

Comment: As a sidenote, I assume you meant `/usr/bin/env`?

Comment: yes thats what i meant @ssmy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either escape the `/` with `\` or use a different delimiter for sed.

Sed can also use delimiters like `_` or `%`